# How to set a Slack reminder only to notify a subset of the people in the channel

Tags: chat, slack, slack-api

I need to set up a reminder in a channel, but this reminder should not send a notification to all the people in the channel but only to a particular subset.

I tried what shown below.

```
/reminder @user1 @user2 @user3 A message every 30 days
```

But when I verify it, slack add " after the first user, which tells me that the reminder would be sent only to the first user and not the others.

```
I will remind @user1 “@user2 @user3 A message” at 9AM Monday, April 1st.
```

Will slack send the notification only to user1 or to all them? (As mentioned). 
Does Slack have the feature to send reminders to multiple users without disturbing the whole channel?

 We don't want to create a separate channel.

Comment: It will only send to the first user if you do it that way. I believe you can use @group, but only on paid tiers.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken > I’m sorry! Reminders can’t be set for User Groups, but you can set a reminder for a channel those users are in. Just be sure to mention the User Group in the body of the reminder!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Slack will only notify the first user you mention in the remind command.

Slack's reminder command supports only Users and Channels so you cannot create a group to notify a large group of people.

You will probably have to create a separate channel to notify them or create a bot using slack that does that if you want to create a special integration for that

Answer (score 3):

If it is a recurring group of people that you usually want to notify together, you can add them to a group and notify the group.

[Slack User Group Documentation](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/212906697-Create-a-user-group)

[Official Source saying `/remind` supports groups](https://slackhq.com/never-forget-the-little-things-with-remind)